# uDeploy secure component property remains encrypted in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, encryption, udeploy

I'm trying to configure a uDeploy property in a script. Have a "pass" variable, which I'm trying to either write to a file or use in a script.

Have tried the following:

`echo ${p:pass} >> /tmp/variable.txt
echo "${p:pass}" >> /tmp/variable.txt
echo '${p:pass}' >> /tmp/variable.txt`

which all give `****` in '/tmp/variable.txt.
Same thing happens in the command.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since you have configured pass as Secure , use a non secure variable for this

[image]